# Universal clipboard between macOS sierra and iOS 10 doesn't seem to work okay!

Tags: macbook-pro, ios, iphone, copy-paste, macos

I've installed macOS sierra (beta) on my MBP & iOS 10 (beta) on my iPhone 5S. Both of them have the latest release. I've connected them in the same wifi network and Bluetooth connection is also active on both of them. So the two-way copy-paste should work seamlessly on these devices. The problem is, copying on MBP & pasting on iPhone works fine **but the reverse doesn't.** What to do to make this working??

Comment: It's a beta. Things might not work correctly.

Comment: @IronCraftMan okay I understand

Comment: I upgraded my iPhone 6 with iOS 10.0.1 a few days ago and upgrade my MacBook Air 13 inch (early-2015) with macOS Sierra official release from Mac App Store this morning. And the problem is exactly the same. Mac copying -> iPhone pasting works, but the reverse doesn't.

Comment: Same problem here: https://discussions.apple.com/thread/7677909

Comment: And here: https://discussions.apple.com/thread/7675824

Comment: Given that both desktop and iPhone OS were in beta when this was asked, AND that both OS versions are now final (not to mention 2 versions ago) - is the question still relevant? I understood questions about beta Apple software were not generally approved for this forum...

Answer (score 1):

I solve the problem by restarting the iPhone 6. Then Universal Clipboard works as expected.